# Can NADP be converted to NADPH using d glucose?

Tags: biochemistry, lab-reagents

For one of our reaction, we require NADPH enzyme. We have NADP in our stock. Is it possible to convert NADP to NADPH using D-glucose anhydrous and if so please provide me how to go about it?

Comment: Reduction potential of NADP⁺ is [-0.32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_standard_reduction_potentials_for_half-reactions_important_in_biochemistry) and that of glucuronic acid to glucose is [0.05](http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/pshapley/genchem2/b9/2.html). So, I guess that glucose oxidation to glucuronic acid cannot reduce NADP⁺.

Comment: @tomd you would also need the enzyme. I assumed that OP wants to use the property of reducing sugars to reduce NADP.